# Join Stored Procedure for Dynamic Pivot to Existing View in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, dynamic, pivot

I have a view in SQL Server 2008 that has 22 columns and about 90 rows. I also want to use dynamic `PIVOT` to get multiple columns of additional notes added to each row.

Is there a way to join these two? I have tried creating a table to store the dynamic pivot info, but since I do not know how many columns or the column names, this did not work for me.

This is what I have so for.

```
Select * From bcvEqInfo
```

With results similar to this

```
+----+------------+-----------+------+-------+
| Co | EquipCode  | EquipName | Vin  | etc   |
+----+------------+-----------+------+-------+
| 1  | 1-0000-001 | D10N-1    | 1234 | asdfs |
| 1  | 1-0000-002 | D10N-2    | 4567 | afda  |
| 1  | 1-0000-003 | D10N-3    | 8910 | adfs  |
+----+------------+-----------+------+-------+
```

I am using the following for my dynamic pivot; with the number of columns with date Header growing as more dates are added.

```
Declare @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(Max) = ''
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
select @ColumnNames += QUOTENAME(Name) + ','
from udEqNotes
SET @ColumnNames = LEFT(@ColumnNames,LEN(@ColumnNames)-1)
--Print @ColumnNames
SET @SQL =
'select * from
(Select Co, Equipment, Name, Notes
from udEqNotes)PivotDate
pivot
(Max(Notes)
for Name in (' + @ColumnNames + ')
) as Pivoting'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

With results like this

```
    +----+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
    | Co | EquipCode  | 110117       | 110217       | 110317       |
    +----+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
    | 1  | 1-0000-001 | D10N-1 Note1 | D10N-1 Note2 | D10N-1 Note3 |
    | 1  | 1-0000-002 | D10N-2 Note1 | D10N-2 Note2 | D10N-2 Note3 |
    | 1  | 1-0000-003 | D10N-3 Note1 | D10N-3 Note2 | D10N-3 Note3 |
    +----+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Ideally I would like results to be

```
+----+------------+-----------+------+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| Co | EquipCode  | EquipName | Vin  | etc   | 110117       | 110217       | 110317       |
| 1  | 1-0000-001 | D10N-1    | 1234 | asdfs | D10N-1 Note1 | D10N-1 Note2 | D10N-1 Note3 |
| 1  | 1-0000-002 | D10N-2    | 4567 | afda  | D10N-2 Note1 | D10N-2 Note2 | D10N-2 Note3 |
| 1  | 1-0000-003 | D10N-3    | 8910 | adfs  | D10N-3 Note1 | D10N-3 Note2 | D10N-3 Note3 |
+----+------------+-----------+------+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Have you considered trying to use a [Table-Valued User-Defined Function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx)?

Comment: I have not, I will look into it.

Comment: @GordThompson, I can not get the the Dynamic Pivot to work in a Function.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track when you "tried creating a table to store the dynamic pivot info". I originally thought that a local #temporary table might do the trick, but as it turned out I needed to use a global ##temporary table.

For example tables

```
[product]

product  description
-------  -------------------
bacon    thin strips of pork
ham      big hunk of pork


[sales]

id  product  region  sales_qty
--  -------  ------  ---------
 1  bacon    North          10
 2  ham      North           6
 3  bacon    South           7
 4  ham      South           9
```

this stored procedure

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE PivotAndJoin AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @regionlist NVARCHAR(max) = N'';
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = N'CREATE TABLE ##pivottemp (product NVARCHAR(20)';
    DECLARE @region NVARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE crsr CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT region FROM sales;
    OPEN crsr;
    FETCH NEXT FROM crsr INTO @region;
    DECLARE @listseparator NVARCHAR(1) = N'';
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql += N', ' + QUOTENAME(@region) + N' INT';
        SET @regionlist += @listseparator + QUOTENAME(@region);
        IF LEN(@listseparator) = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @listseparator = N',';
        END;
        FETCH NEXT FROM crsr INTO @region;
    END;
    CLOSE crsr;
    DEALLOCATE crsr;
    SET @sql += N')';
    -- @regionlist example:
    --   [North],[South]
    -- @sql example:
    --   CREATE TABLE ##pivottemp (product NVARCHAR(20), [North] INT, [South] INT)
    BEGIN TRY
        DROP TABLE ##pivottemp;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- ignore error (assume table simply didn't exist)
    END CATCH
    EXECUTE(@sql);
    SET @sql = 
            N'INSERT INTO ##pivottemp (product, ' + @regionlist + N') ' +
            N'SELECT product, ' + @regionlist +
            N'  FROM (SELECT product, region, sales_qty FROM sales) AS SourceTable ' +
            N'  PIVOT (SUM([sales_qty]) FOR [region] IN (' + @regionlist + N')) AS results';
    EXECUTE(@sql);
    SET @sql =
            N'SELECT product.product, product.description, ' + @regionlist + 
            N'  FROM ##pivottemp INNER JOIN product ' +
            N'      ON product.product = ##pivottemp.product';
    EXECUTE(@sql);
END
```

produced

```
product  description          North  South
-------  -------------------  -----  -----
bacon    thin strips of pork     10      7
ham      big hunk of pork         6      9
```